# Dropdown menu won't move objects down

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, menu

I'm instantiating objects/prefabs into a vertical layout group in Unity. each of these objects have a dropdown menus, but my issues is that when I'm expanding the dropdown menu, it does not push the other elements in the layout group down.

What I want these prefabs to do, is that they should be able move the other objects down in order for things to not overlap.

Edit:

[How it looks when pressed play in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkEkM.png)

[The script that instantiates the prefab that has the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIFTu.png)

Comment: Can you add a picture of it? Also, the code which instantiates and pushes into the dropdown layout.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you could add a component called ContentSizeFitter to the parent game object, and set vertical fit to min size. All the child element should add a LayoutElement with a specific min size